# Access PHP Error Logs - Vagrant CentOS VM setup by Puphpet

Tags: php, apache, logging, centos, vagrant

I have a Vagrant VM running CentOS, which was built from a puphpet file (config.yaml), and I'm trying to get the PHP error logs setup and accessible.

**config.yaml - PHP section:**

```
php:
install: '1'
settings:
    version: '56'
modules:
    php:
        - cli
        - intl
        - mcrypt
    pear: {  }
    pecl:
        - pecl_http
ini:
    display_errors: Off
    error_reporting: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
    session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    date.timezone: America/Denver
    log_errors: On
    error_log: /var/log/php_errors.log
fpm_ini:
    error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
fpm_pools:
    phpfp_tg4gv8zscipk:
        ini:
            prefix: www
            listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
            security.limit_extensions: .php
            user: www-user
            group: www-data
composer: '1'
composer_home: ''
```

**/etc/php.d/zzzz_custom.ini**

```
[CUSTOM]
log_errors=true
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
session.save_path=/var/lib/php/session
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
date.timezone=America/Denver
error_log=/var/log/php_errors.log
display_errors=false
```

**/etc/php.ini**

```
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
log_errors = On
```

I've done:

```
sudo touch /var/log/php_errors.log
sudo chown www-data: /var/log/php_errors.log
sudo chmod +rw /var/log/php_errors.log
```

When I run the following, I get nothing:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/php_errors.log
```

I know there should be PHP errors as I explicitly creating them in a certain file to test, such as using undeclared functions, etc.

I've also tried not setting `error_log` in both the config.yaml and the php.ini file to see if the default would work, as I thought it would dump PHP errors into `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

I seriously have no idea where to go from here. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let Puphpet create your `vhost` file, please check what error logs were specified in there. I had this problem a while back and found extra error logs when I went through all my `nginx` logs in `/var/log`.

For `nginx` and `apache` you should be checking the contents `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` respectively for the `vhost` files.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to put:

```
phpinfo(); 
exit;
```

Into your index.php file and look for the error_log setting there. Then at least you'll know what php thinks it's doing, rather than only knowing what puphpet might be telling php to do.

Hope this is helpful.